# Laravel model accessor with attribute name containing a number is ignored

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, accessor

In Laravel 5.7 in my database I have a property containing a number in its name - item_1_quality. When I create an accessor with method name using camel case it is ignored.

I have tried various combinations the most obvious of which was

```
public function getItem1QualityAttribute($value)
{
    dd($value);
}
```

however, it does not work. I tried other possible combinations without success. I am properly calling the property as other accessors in the same model work fine. The problem seems to be related to the naming.

Comment: As described in https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27035
adding the property to appends gets the accessor called but the value is always null and does not come from the database.

Comment: Make yourself life easier with `getItemOneQualityAttribute`.

Comment: @Tpojka Sometimes an application is old, created by someone else and such naming may be both in code and in the database making it impractical to change,

Comment: True that. Although it worths to check through IDE search engine what time it could take for well refactoring and naming convention (how many occurrences). In my experience one variable name in very complex application can't take much more than two hours of refactoring (in less complex lot less than that) but it strips off lot of technical debt.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a hacky but a working solution which someone might find helpful.

1. Add attribute to appends

   ```
   protected $appends = ['product_1_quality'];
   ```
2. Create the following accessor:

   ```
    public function getProduct1QualityAttribute()
    {
        $value = $this->attributes['product_1_quality']);
        // do something with your $value and return.
    }
   ```

The $value as argument will not work - access using the $attributes array.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to upgrade to the latest version, you have lots of new features and PHP 8.1. I had to migrate a project from 5.8 to 6.x, it was very difficult as it was a gigant monolyth, but with dedication, we were able to make it work, else you will always suffer with this pesky type of things